# Searching a value in excel cell corresponding to a option present in other cell

Tags: vba, excel

How can I search a value in excel cell corresponding to an option present in other cell?

I have a cell which has data as follows:

```
A. Cat
B. Dog
C. Elephant
D. Rat
```

and other cell has data - `B`

Now I need to write a macro which will fetch the value corresponding to `B` option i.e. - `Dog`.

Comment: Have you tried any codes?

Comment: I was not able to start . I got confused about how to start

Comment: A-D are in a single cell?

Comment: have a look at VLOOKUP

Comment: @bioschaf- A-D is a single cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the cell value:

```
Dim val as String
val = Sheets(nameofsheet).Cells(row,column)
```

Set the range where you want to search

```
Dim rng as Range
Set rng = Sheets(nameofsheet).Range(cell1, cell2)
```

Get the result with .Find method

```
Dim result as Range
Set result = rng.Find(val, lookin:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
```